# How to show only relevant email on TO Address using php mailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

How do I hide other emails when sending emails using phpmailer? I'm getting emails from the database.
The code is sending mails to all but on the headers on **TO** its showing all emails. Please help my code is as follows:

```php
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM subscribers");
$stmt->execute();
$results= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($results as $row){
    $mail->addAddress($row['email']); 
}
```

Comment: OK, you don't want the email addresses to appear in the `TO` field of the emails. I get it now.

Comment: i want to send emails to all subscribers in my table but show only relevant email to the subscribers' TO HEADER

Comment: If you want that you have to send each subscriber an individual email, more or less like in the answer of jpneey. However there's also the `$mail->addBcc($row['email'])` option. The so-called _"blind carbon copy"_. See: https://phpmailer.github.io/PHPMailer/classes/PHPMailer.PHPMailer.PHPMailer.html#method_addBCC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the send function inside the loop, however this is resource expensive on large datasets.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM subscribers");
$stmt->execute();
$results= $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach($results as $row){
    $mail->addAddress($row['email']); 
    $mail->Send();
    $mail->clearAddresses();
}
```

You can also use this as a reference for a much more efficient way of doing this

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps

As mention by `KIKO Software` from the comments above, if the email is not *personalized* for each users then you can use `$mail->addBcc($row['email'])` inside the loop and send all emails on bulk.

```
// add a main email address
$mail->addAddress('an_email_here');
foreach($results as $row){
    // then just bcc other emails.
    $mail->addBcc($row['email'])
}
$mail->Send()
```

Note: this will also appear to users that the emails are just `BCC`ed

Comment: A caution note to this answer: As you mention it is very resource expensive and also quite slow to send one mail at a time. This means that when the script has sent, say 50-100 emails, it will timeout and exit (default is after 30 seconds). It is therefore necessary to use the function `set_time_limit([x seconds]);` to avoid suddenly stopped script.... But there are of course better solutions than using this method :)

Comment: sorry phpmailer im not familiar, so i have added the above, i got the error "message body is empty" i then include the body inside the loop i now get duplicate emails the TO header hasn't changed. The second options is giving me the same result i changed the whole code to second result and the header TO is still the same

Comment: @the_guru please add more details on your code above, for us to see on how you are sending the emails

Comment: While you linked to the right example, your code misses a critical line. You must call `$mail->clearAddresses()` after `send()` inside your loop as otherwise you'll end up sending vastly more messages than you intend because `addAddress` *adds* an address, it doesn't *set* the recipient list.

Comment: Thanks @Synchro. Sorry, about that. I have updated my answer

Comment: @jpneey thanks i added the following   $mail->Send();
    $mail->clearAddresses();
       } and it worked